# How to post Movies I've "Watched" or "Want to Watch" via Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, collections, facebook-opengraph, movies

I would like to be able to have my application's users have the ability to add movies they've "Watched" to their Timeline - specifically in the "**Movies**" collection of their Timeline, as show here:

[image]

It appears that these activities are solely published via the "**Movies**" application (an internal Facebook-controlled application). Is there no way to programmatically add a movie to one of these collections via the `video_watches` or `video_wants_to_watch` action?

I can see that any application can post via these actions via the documentation

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/video.watches/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/video.wants_to_watch/

but they end up "sandboxed" under a different application's Collection (if the application has a Collection set up for that particular action/object pair).

Additionally, there seems to be no way to tie an application's collection data to the Movies collection like the Music collection seems to - which is how I would assume the third-party application's `video_watches` data would append or combine with Facebook's "**Movies**" application data.

I have tried to follow the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#datatodefaultsections to create a URL with which to integrate the application data, but it does not appear to function at all.

https://www.facebook.com/me/movies?[appname] simply does nothing. It just brings you to the "**Movies**" collection on your Timeline with no option to add your app's data to that section. Nothing like what's shown here ([from the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#datatodefaultsections)) for **Music**, giving you the option to add your application's data to the Movies collection:

[image]

Is this something exclusive only to the "**Music**" collection at this point? When will the other "first-party" collections (other than **Music**) accept "third-party" application data?

See also related questions:

- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15759032/facebook-api-to-get-watched-movies-tv-show-list-or-read-book-list
- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15886745/how-does-one-enable-an-apps-data-to-be-added-to-users-default-sections

Comment: Also see the following screengrabs:  

- [Option to Add Apps to Movies](http://i.imgur.com/LRL2fgQ.png)
- [No Movie Apps to Add](http://i.imgur.com/Ta7ikfJ.png)

Comment: Silly question, you keep saying sandboxed... did your action actually get approved?

Comment: I can post on `/me/video.watches` but it does not appear in the watched list either. I also noticed that the message in the timeline is slightly different ("Régis has watched XXX" vs "Régis has added XXX to: Watched movies").
 Goodreads has been able to change the content of the books, but maybe they have had a priviledged access to the API.

Answer (score 1):

You need open graph items to use this method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.wants_to_watch

If you use a open graph object of type movie.other you can use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.wants_to_watch?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=POST&other=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F467235199955838
```

I use trakt.tv to get the movie open graph objects. For example if you want to add [Star Wars Episode VI](http://trakt.tv/movie/star-wars-episode-vi-return-of-the-jedi-1983) to your whatchlist on facebook you can use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.wants_to_watch?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=POST&movie=http://trakt.tv/movie/star-wars-episode-vi-return-of-the-jedi-1983
```

Note that in trakt.tv the open graph is movie.

You can also do the same to add watched movies, rate it, add books, music... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type